# html5Mode doesn't link to base url

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I'm using AngularJS 1.3.2 with html5Mode on. My app is hosted on `http://localhost/app`

My base is set to

```
<base href="/app/">
```

I'm trying to create a link to the app root, but when i do

```
<a ng-href="/">Home</a>
```

it points me to `http://localhost`, but i need it to point me to `http://localhost/app`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution is:

```
<a ng-href="./">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution seems to be to not use a slash at all (not sure which is better)

`<a href="heroes">Heros</a>`

Rather than

`<a href="/heroes">Heros</a>`